# How can I install libstdc++6 for my app on Heroku?

Tags: linux, heroku, executable, sudo, lib

I'm trying to run a Python app on Heroku which spawns a Linux executable.

I get the error:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found
```

All solutions to this problem I have found use `sudo`.

If I open a bash terminal with heroku CLI

```
heroku run bash
```

and type

```
sudo
```

I get

```
bash: sudo: command not found
```

So I cannot run

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

Comment: You have built a program with a newer version of libstdc++ than Heroku supports.  Easiest would be to build with an older GCC.

Comment: The problem is that I'm on Windows. I don't know how to build for Linux.The Linux executable I want to use I just downloaded. However I can build the same program for Windows from source.

Comment: Side note: don't install anything interactively as you tried to do. Heroku's ephemeral filesystem will cause changes to be lost the next time your dyno restarts, which happens at least once per day. Instead, make sure your dependencies are provided by the stack (as you've done below) or built into your application slug at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

Upgraded Heroku app to latest stack ( `heroku-18` instead of default `heroku-16` ) using Heroku CLI

```
heroku stack:set heroku-18 -a <app name>
```

Then I had to make a git push so that the app is rebuilt with new stack.

Now it works.

Yes, `heroku-18` is beta, but as long as it works, I don't mind.

Comment: That makes sense.  You resolved the problem by upgrading to a newer operating system, effectively--and that OS came with a new enough version of GNU's libstdc++ that it is compatible with the Linux executable you downloaded.  For future reference, the alternative solution would have been to download an older build of that Linux executable.